# (Js) number method to add a comma after the first number and remove the 2 number after comma ?? is there any?

Tags: javascript

I want to format a number to two decimal places. Say the user enters `8764444` it should be formatted as `8.76`. is there some built-in function in javascript to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no built in method for exactly that, but you can use the `substr` method to get parts of a string to do the formatting:

```js
var input = "8764444";

input = input.substr(0, 1) + '.' + input.substr(1, 2);

// show result in Stackoverflow snippet
document.write(input);
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.